# How do I get "realtime" updates from a database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, real-time, database

I'm planning on making a web application with Angular and mongoDB that will be a 'side app' for a boardgame. So for instance the first player to get 10 points will win that game. I want every other player that joined the same game(each on their own phones) on the webapplication to get a notification when someone reached the 10 points.

So I'm wondering how can I send out a notification to all other players when one player reached the limit of 10 points. Is this even possible and if yes, what is the best way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're considering using a noSQL DB then I think you should checkout https://rethinkdb.com, It has change feeds builtin. It works well for real time updates.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way is to use a timer to call your API at a certain invertal to check if the player has reach the amount of point. This works but isn't the optimal solution. For real "realtime" I would suggest looking into socket techonology. Some library like [socket.io](http://socket.io) that allows you to plugs a nodeJs server with socket support. This would be the ideal solution. You could call the NodeJs server once you have reach your amount of point and then your socket would call your front-end to update it.